# Constness of template member in const member function

Tags: c++, function, templates, constants, member

How is `const` applied to a template member in a `const` member function? I found the following to be interesting (this is in VS15):

```
class TcpSocket;

class TcpThread
{
   TcpSocket* Listener() const;
   std::vector< TcpSocket* > sockets_;
};

TcpSocket* TcpThread::Listener() const
{
   auto s = sockets_.front();
   return s;
}
```

I added the `auto` to clarify what was going on.  It is deduced as `TcpSocket*`, so the non-const version of `front` is being selected.  However, if I insert

```
sockets_.erase(sockets_.begin());
```

as the first line of code, it fails to compile, essentially saying that `sockets_` is `const`.

It makes sense for it to work as it does, but there is evidently more going on here than simply "treat each member as `const` in a `const` member function.

Comment: const at the end of the member function declaration means the fucntion is not changing the object, so compiler will give you an error if you alter meber variables, the first example just copies it which allows it to copy to a non const version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sockets_` inside `Listener` is `const`. Let's have a look at what `front` returns:

```
reference front();
const_reference front() const;
```

So we'll get a `const_reference`, in this case a `TcpSocket * const&`.

This is where your expectation is incorrect. Stripping away the reference for sake of clarity, you expect a `const TcpSocket*`, it gives you a `TcpSocket * const`. The former is a pointer to a `const TcpSocket`, the latter is a `const` pointer to a `TcpSocket`.

So what `front` gives you is a pointer which you can't change to a `TcpSocket` which you *can* change.

As such, it's perfectly valid to make a non-const copy of this pointer with its pointee available for modification:

```
auto s = sockets_.front();
//sockets_.front() returns TcpSocket* const
//s copies it to a TcpSocket*
```

Comment: For combining both the technical and the semantic aspects, +1.

Comment: This really explained it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the non-const version of `front` is called, it's just that you're storing pointers, and then you're putting it into `auto` which always deduces by-value (and not by reference--for which you need `auto& =`). Because you're copying the const pointer, you then have your own copy, and so `const` is omitted for it, unless you explicitly define it that way. That's why you're deducing `TcpSocket*` instead of `TcpSocket* const`.

If you want to verify this, try doing `auto& s = _sockets.front()` and see what type you get *then*.

Note. too, that since you're storing a pointer, that `vector::const_reference` you'd get back would be point to a *const pointer* and not a *pointer to const*.

The *container* itself, being const in that scope, means that you can't change its sequence of elements, or what they point to. So you can't say `_sockets.erase()` nor can you say `_sockets[0]`. *However*, since the elements themselves are pointers to a non-const `TcpSocket`, that means that you can do pretty much whatever you want with them. It's the *container* you can't fiddle with.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `std::vector< TcpSocket* > sockets_;` is *itself* `const`, the containee (i.e. `TcpSocket*`) is **not** `const`.

That's why you get the non-`const` deduction.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front -- Note `const_reference` being returned by the const version of `front()`.

Comment: @YamMarcovic: It returns a const reference to a pointer to non-constant memory.

Comment: This is a much better answer than one by Yam. It explains what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why you do not get `TcpSocket * const`:

Although `front()` returns `TcpSocket* const &`, `auto` is deduced to be `TcpSocket*`.

Consider:

```
double const & foo(); 
// ...
double const a = 4.0;
auto b = a; // valid, decltype(b) === double
double c = a; // valid, too
double d = foo(); // valid
auto e = foo(); // decltype(e) === double
```

You're making a copy anyway, so why would that copy be `const`?
You do not get anything valueable from having `s` being `TcpSocket * const`.

#### Why you do not get `TcpSocket const *`:

That's just because you store `TcpSocket*` in the vector. The `const`ness of `front()` makes sure that the stored pointer is not altered (i.e. you cannot make `sockets_.front()` point to another `TcpSocket` from within `Listener()`) but maintining `const`-correctness of the object pointed to is due to the user.